# Leave rxjs-for-await loop programatically

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-observables

I have app that opens stream where server pumps SSEs.
I want the loop to run until desired value arrives, then leave the loop and continue.
I've looked at `takeWhile` operator, but couldn't find a way to implement it. I also don't know how could I `unsubscribe` and since the stream never completes...

```
const stream = this.sseService.returnAsObservable();
      for await (const data of eachValueFrom(stream)) {
        console.log(data);
        if (data.jobid === "JOB05879") {
          this.sseService.stopConnection();
          // how to get out now?
        }
      }
      console.log('we are out');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, mixing promises and observables is an anti-pattern. If you don't mind that, then here's a way to get only the first data where data.jobid === "JOB05879". You don't need for-await as you're just expecting 1 value from this stream.

```js
const stream = this.sseService.returnAsObservable().pipe(
  filter(data => data.jobid === "JOB05879"),
  first()
);

data = await stream.toPromise();
console.log(data);
this.sseService.stopConnection();
console.log('we are done');
```

Without promises:

```js
const stream = this.sseService.returnAsObservable().pipe(
  filter(data => data.jobid === "JOB05879"),
  first()
).subscribe({
  next: data => {
    console.log(data);
    this.sseService.stopConnection();
  },
  error: _ console.log("Data with jobid JOB05879 not found"),
  complete: () => console.log("We are done");
});
```

#### Update #1: Using forkJoin

You wrote the following which first grabs an array of `finito` and then uses that array as input for your `notes`.

```js
const finito = await forkJoin([     
  this.jobsService.submitTestJob('blabla1').pipe(first()),     
  this.jobsService.submitTestJob('blabla2').pipe(first())
]).toPromise(); 

const notes = await forkJoin([     
  this.sseService.returnAsObservable().pipe(
    filter((d: any) => d.jobid === finito[0].jobid), 
    first()
  ),     
  this.sseService.returnAsObservable().pipe(
    filter((d: any) => d.jobid === finito[1].jobid), 
    first()
  ) 
]).toPromise();
```

That should work, though there's a bunch of error checking you should do.

This can actually be simplified using RxJS operators so that you're not waiting on each `finito`

```js
const notes = await merge(
  this.jobsService.submitTestJob('blabla1').pipe(first()),
  this.jobsService.submitTestJob('blabla2').pipe(first()),
  this.jobsService.submitTestJob('blabla3').pipe(first()),
  this.jobsService.submitTestJob('blabla4').pipe(first()),
  this.jobsService.submitTestJob('blabla5').pipe(first()),
).pipe(
  mergeMap(finito => this.sseService.returnAsObservable().pipe(
    filter((d: any) => d.jobid === finito.jobid), 
    first()
  )),
  toArray()
).toPromise();
```

And another step to make it even more concise, if you'd like:

```js
const notes = await from([
  "blabla1", 
  "blabla2", 
  "blabla3", 
  "blabla4", 
  "blabla5"
]).pipe(
  mergeMap(blabla => 
    this.jobsService.submitTestJob(blabla).pipe(first())
  ),
  mergeMap(finito => this.sseService.returnAsObservable().pipe(
    filter((d: any) => d.jobid === finito.jobid), 
    first()
  )),
  toArray()
).toPromise();
```

Even more concise:

```js
const notes = await from([1,2,3,4,5]).pipe(
  map(num => `blabla${num}`),
  mergeMap(blabla => 
    this.jobsService.submitTestJob(blabla).pipe(first())
  ),
  mergeMap(finito => this.sseService.returnAsObservable().pipe(
    filter((d: any) => d.jobid === finito.jobid), 
    first()
  )),
  toArray()
).toPromise();
```

#### Making only 1 call to sseService

From the look of your example code, it seems it should be possible for you to make just one call to this.sseService.returnAsObservable(). It can filter through any of the allowable jobs.

That might look like this:

```js
const params = [1,2,3,4,5];
const notes = await from(params).pipe(
  map(num => `blabla${num}`),
  mergeMap(blabla => 
    this.jobsService.submitTestJob(blabla).pipe(first())
  ),
  toArray(),
  mergeMap(finitoArray => this.sseService.returnAsObservable().pipe(
    filter(d => finitoArray.map(f => f.jobid).includes(d.jobid))
  )),
  take(params.length),
  toArray()
).toPromise();
```

and to take this example back to the two-stage code you wrote, that would look like this:

```js
const params = [1,2,3,4,5];
const streams = params
  .map(num => `blabla${num}`)
  .map(blabla => this.jobsService.submitTestJob(blabla).pipe(first())

const finito = await forkJoin(streams).toPromise(); 

const notes = await this.sseService.returnAsObservable().pipe(
  filter(d => finitoArray.map(f => f.jobid).includes(d.jobid)),
  take(params.length),
  toArray()
).toPromise();
```

Comment: I think I have to live with the anti-pattern, since parts on my app's work need to be done in sequence (prepare environment) and then it can be in parallel (launch the jobs).
What if I wanted the for await for the first example of yours? Sometimes I'd need to launch eg. 5 jobs, that can run in parallel, but I wanna move on only after I know how they finished

Comment: The only time you have to live with the antipattern is if you're using a library that expects promises. Otherwise, observables can do everything that promises can do and more. That being said, you can just await a `forkJoin`ed stream to get an array of results from your 5 jobs.

Comment: I see, I took my shot at implementation

`const finito = await forkJoin([
    this.jobsService.submitTestJob('blabla1').pipe(first()),
    this.jobsService.submitTestJob('blabla2').pipe(first())
]).toPromise();
const notes = await forkJoin([
    this.sseService.returnAsObservable().pipe(filter((d: any) => d.jobid === finito[0].jobid), first()),
    this.sseService.returnAsObservable().pipe(filter((d: any) => d.jobid === finito[1].jobid), first())
]).toPromise();`

What happens if the job finishes (and notification arrives) before all are submitted -> the `finito` gets resolved?

Comment: `forkJoin` doesn't emit anything until all source observables have emitted.I've updated with a version that doesn't use two stages and just makes the next call the moment the previous call comes in. Then a made a few other versions to give you some more examples of RxJS at work

Comment: Wow, amazing explanation, thanks! I usually tried to stay away from the RxJS operators, but they are so helpful as I see now :-)